# Parent model method is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm an absolute beginner to Ruby on Rails; I literally started last night.  I'm following the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial, although I've made a few modifications.  Instead of a blog with posts and comments, I'm making a simple task-tracking application in which Projects have Tasks associated with them.

Everything was going quite well until [step #9 (Deleting Comments)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-comments).  According to the tutorial, I should be able to get the parent model for a comment by calling `comment.post`, the analogue of which in my case is `task.project`.  But when Rails tries to render the partial in which I've got `task.project`, it raises a NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `project' for #<Task:0x7fb0011cf058>
```

My models are as follows:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => :true

  belongs_to :project
end
```

Using the rails console, I determined that my tasks do have a `project_id` method which returns the ID of the associated project.  Thus, I can get around the problem by using `Project.find(task.project_id)` instead of `task.project` in my partial.  That seems "wrong," though, and makes me wonder if the relationship between my two models is somehow broken.

What's going on here?

**Update:** If I comment out the `validates` line in the Task model, then all of its methods work properly.  I don't understand why that is the case, though.

**Update 2:** Figured it out.  I was using the symbol `:true` instead of the simple boolean value in the `validates` line of my Task model.  Had I paid more attention to the stack trace in the first place, I would have figured it out much sooner.  What an embarrassing mistake!

Comment: Does Task have a name attribute? Maybe you could include the relevant chunks of your `schema.rb` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks perfect. But if you were trying that into console try reloading first and then try again

```
reload!
task = Task.find(<record-id>)
task.project
```

It should be working.

Comment: I closed and re-opened the console and Rails server multiple times while trying to debug the issue, so I don't think that's the cause.  I tried your suggestion anyway, and unfortunately it did not help.  It also seems that my Task class doesn't have a `find` method... not sure if that's related to my other problem.  
`irb(main):002:0> @task = Task.find(1)
ArgumentError: :true is an invalid option. Expecting true, Hash, Regexp, Range, or Array`

Comment: @Mitch: Do you have another class called "Task" somewhere? Try `Task.superclass` in the console and see what it has to say.

Comment: @mu, I tried `Task.superclass` and it threw the same Exception as above.  In the stack trace I noticed something about validation so I commented out the validates line in the model, and now all of the methods (including `project`) work.  I am still not sure why that might be happening.  I'll update the original question with this information.